# JavaFX Combobox listener for user changes only

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I tried to implement a listener on a ComboBox that validates the user's selection and resets it to the previous value if the selection is invalid.

My problem now is that the listener on valueProperty or selectedItemProperty also recognizes programmatically made changes e.g. when the user selects another entity, which subsequently changes the ComboBox value.

Is there any way to implement a listener that only listens for changes committed by the user?

```
        stateComboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, State oldValue,
                State newValue) 
        {
            if(stateCheckActive==false) return;
            if(newValue==null||oldValue.equals(newValue)) return;

            currentDocument.getBean().setStatus(oldValue);      

            if(service.changeStateAllowed(currentDocument.getBean(), newState.getId().getNr(), true))
            {
                stateCheckActive=false;

                newDocument=service.updateDocument(currentDocument.getBean());
                currentDocument.setBean(newDocument);

                stateCheckActive=true;
            }
            else 
            {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        stateCheckActive=false;
                        statusComboBox.setValue(oldValue);
                        stateCheckActive=true;
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: no .. and why would you need it? The programmatic change produces valid changes only, so doesn't matter whether the validator is running or not, it will pass

Comment: The problem is that a valid value triggers an update to a database and reloads the entity, which then leads to a deadlock because the ComboBox Value changes again. I think I might try it with flags, as there seems to be no user selection event.

Comment: sounds like something wrong in the code you are not showing - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    private ChangeListener<? super String> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue.matches("[A-Z]*")) { // put your validation here
            comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().removeListener(getListener());
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue);
                comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(getListener());
            });
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.add("VALID");
        items.add("MATCHES");
        items.add("NotMatches");
        items.add("RandomValue");
        comboBox.setItems(items);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(getListener());
    }

    private ChangeListener<? super String> getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

}
```

Comment: beware - whatever you want to achieve with runlater, it's unreliable: it only guarantees that it runs "later" whithout specifying what that is!!

Comment: You are right, but can it is less likely, to not be executed in the right time that code fragment, I don't really see any case  when it can cause serious problem, but I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: I think the OP is doing something wrong in his setup, so no need for gripping straws ;) My personal rule is to never-ever use runlater in fx contexts because you simply cant know when it will happen.

Comment: But when we are talking about "when" it is in a range of some ms, which at the most of the cases doesn't matter, especially in a JavaFx app when you don't have 1k+ users and  so on. There are a few places where I could not avoid using it. One case is this answer, I didn't find  any better solution to prevent the user from selection a wrong item if there is something not okay. If you know any better solution for this problem I would  also appreciate :)

Comment: but you are trying to solve a problem that the OP doesn't have (at least as I read it) - the validation seems to be okay, but throws up if the combo is reloaded .. as to your usage of runlater, well, I'm happy it works for you but also happy I don't have to maintain any code you wrote with it <g>

Comment: Thank you, I implemented a solution similiar to your solution, but instead of adding and removing the listener I added a flag to switch the listener on and off. It now does not trigger the listener anymore after the entity is changed.